# Error Message in Android Studio. Could not find app compat V7 even if Android Support Repository is installed

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-appcompat

I ran into this problem where the app can't find app compat v7. This is from build.gradle:

> Error:Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0. Searched
>   in the following locations:
>       https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/appcompat-v7-23.1.0.pom
>       https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/appcompat-v7-23.1.0.jar
>       file:/Users/ITSME/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/appcompat-v7-23.1.0.pom
>       file:/Users/ITSME/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/appcompat-v7-23.1.0.jar
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/appcompat-v7-23.1.0.pom
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.0/appcompat-v7-23.1.0.jar
>   Required by:
>       nadi-android-app-fast-food:android:unspecified
>
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK
>   Manager. Open Android SDK Manager

Also, I have already installed Android SDK Manager but it still thinks that I haven't installed it. Could it be the application is looking for them in a different directory? It it does, how do I change it? Is it because I haven't installed the Android API for that particular version? (I have installed just the SDK Platform for every version, not the whole thing)[image]

```
buildscript {
    repositories { 
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    ext.appName = "ePos"

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository"
            url "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/extras/google/m2repository"
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```